# Flash Support for TideSDK App

Tags: flash, tidesdk

I have an app that opens a webpage on user action and that webpage has flash in it and I know 99% of my users already have flash installed in their system, so all i need is to know whether there is a way to play flash video in my app. Or a way for my app to access the already installed flash player on the user's system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system installed flash player will be available inside TideSDK. You should have no problem using the same.